# Dumping table data into CSV

Tags: python, csv, pandas

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

shot_chart_url = 'http://stats.nba.com/stats/shotchartdetail?CFID=33&CFPAR'\
                'AMS=2014-15&ContextFilter=&ContextMeasure=FGA&DateFrom=&D'\
                'ateTo=&GameID=&GameSegment=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Loca'\
                'tion=&MeasureType=Base&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&'\
                'PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=PerGame&Period=0&PlayerID=201935&Plu'\
                'sMinus=N&Position=&Rank=N&RookieYear=&Season=2014-15&Seas'\
                'onSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&TeamID=0&VsConferenc'\
                'e=&VsDivision=&mode=Advanced&showDetails=0&showShots=1&sh'\
                'owZones=0'

# Get the webpage containing the data
response = requests.get(shot_chart_url)
# Grab the headers to be used as column headers for our DataFrame
headers = response.json()['resultSets'][0]['headers']
# Grab the shot chart data
shots = response.json()['resultSets'][0]['rowSet']

shot_df = pd.DataFrame(shots, columns=headers)
# View the head of the DataFrame and all its columns
from IPython.display import display
with pd.option_context('display.max_columns', None):
    display(shot_df.head())
```

I want to dump the data from the pandas table into a CSV but I'm unsure of how to implement pandas.DataFrame.to_csv

Comment: please explain why calling `shot.to_csv()` does not work for you

Comment: shot_df.to_csv() worked for me as stated earlier by Haleemur

Answer (score 0):

Call the DataFrame instance's [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) method with at least the path argument

```
shot_df.to_csv('/path/to/file.csv')
```